# Case insensitive search in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I want to search for Mobile or mobile legend or mobile. it should return both of the arrays. But my code only works if I search for the exact same word. Please help.

```
$resutls = [];
$words = ['mobile', 'Mobile Legend', 'Mobile', 'mobile legend']; 

foreach ($items as $item) {
   if(in_array($item['CategoryName'], $words)) {
      $results[] = $item;
   }
}
print_r($results);
```

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [Name] => Mobile Game,
            [CategoryName] => Mobile Legend
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [Name] => Laptop Game
            [CategoryName] => Mobile
        )
```

Comment: Please supply an example of `$items` that you are looping over.

Comment: Please go and enable proper PHP error reporting – NOW! (Your array keys appear to be `CategoryName`, but you are are trying to access `categoryName` - if that really is the case, then PHP would have already alerted you to that mistake, if only you had let it.)

Comment: @CBroe sir, in my code it is `subCategoryName`. I am accessing it the right way but here I made a mistake while modifying my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$searchTerms = ['mobile', 'Mobile Legend', 'Mobile', 'mobile legend'];
$data = [
  [
    'id' => 1,
    'Name' => "Mobile Game",
    'CategoryName' => "Mobile Legend"
  ],
  [
    'id' => 2,
    'Name' => "Laptop Game",
    'CategoryName' => "Mobile"
  ],
  [
    'id' => 3,
    'Name' => "Something",
    'CategoryName' => "Console"
  ]
];
$output = [];
foreach ($searchTerms as $searchTerm) {

  $pattern = sprintf('/%s/i', preg_quote($searchTerm));

  array_walk($data, function($entry, $index) use ($pattern, &$output) {
    if (!array_key_exists($index, $output)
      && (preg_match($pattern, $entry['Name'])
        || preg_match($pattern, $entry['CategoryName']))) {
      $output[$index] = $entry;
    }
  });

}

print_r($output);
```

The obvious output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [Name] => Mobile Game
            [CategoryName] => Mobile Legend
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [Name] => Laptop Game
            [CategoryName] => Mobile
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! How I can use this inside my forEach loop?

Comment: Re-reading your question I now have the impression that I got your question wrong... Sorry about that. I replaced the code to what I think solves your actual issue: it filters for all entries in the data set that have a "CategoryName" that is matched by any of the search terms in a case insensitive manner.

Comment: sir thanks so much! this is working now! Sir, how can I add one more condition to check if the `Name == "Mobile Game " || Name == "Desktop Game " ` before checking for `CategoryName`?

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly... However... You really should be able to adapt the code yourself, don't you think so?

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir! Yes, I also modified the code. My `$data` array ordinally had 5 entries which I didn't include in the question. After filtering by name, I got 2 entries as in the output. Then I added the searching part. Thanks again:)

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help a bit. Don't forget to give back to the community yourself :-)